# use pmap to increase counter but missed values

Tags: clojure

```
(swap! foo (fn [old] 3))

(pmap
 (fn [_] (swap! foo inc))
 (range 10000))

@foo        ;It prints 1027, which is smaller than 10000.
```

So, why foo is not 10003 ?

Anything to do with laziness ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of `pmap`:

> Semi-lazy in that the                                                                                                                                                                                     parallel computation stays ahead of the consumption, but doesn't
>     realize the entire result unless required. Only useful for
>     computationally intensive functions where the time of f dominates
>     the coordination overhead.

So yes, it's only realizing a few elements. Try wrapping the `pmap` in a `doall` and you'll see your intended result.